# Hybrid app send link to be open by system in android

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid

Let's say that there is a youtube link in my app, what I want is when the user presses it, the link gets opened by the youtube app(if the user has youtube, if he doesn't any other app that can handle this request).
Thus, I want the android system to handle the link, not my app.

Thank you.

Comment: You have nothing to do. This is the default behavior of the android system...

Comment: It is bu,t I use `window.open(link, '_system');` to open the new window and it opens it in the hybrid app.

Comment: Could you call native code instead, just for this part?

Comment: I guess I will research how to do that.

Comment: If you can, this is the code : Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my config.xml I added:

```
<access origin="http://img.youtube.com/*" launch-external="no"/>
<access origin="http://*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="https://*" launch-external="yes" />
```

and removed `<access origin="*"/>`

So when I call `window.open(link, '_system');` now it opens the link in the YouTube App.

more information [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)